# Vlookup or Index and return multiple adjacent rows in next column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I'm not sure this is possible. I have column A which I'm searching for text, then I want to return column B + the 5 adjacent rows below and as separate cells, not a sum. Some of those may be blank. Here's an example of what I'm working with. The position of the number in column B can change, however, I will always want a fixed amount of rows. I have tried using the index but I was hoping for 1 formula to return multiple rows. Here's what I have `=INDEX(B21:B190,MATCH($L$1,A21:A190,0)+1)` (then +2, +3, +4, +5 etc...:

[image]

Comment: This can very well be possible, however right now it looks like you're asking us to do this work for you. This will most likely get you [downvoted](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) and you're unlikely to receive an answer. Perhaps include what effort you have made to solve this, and where you have gotten stuck?

Comment: It is worth to note that one formula cannot populate multiple cells. So your best place to start would be to write different `vlookup` or `index/match` statements that will find your lookup value and return the offset by 1 column and several different rows.

Comment: Thanks very much, I should have included what I have done. One formula can return multiple cells though can it not? I have tried multiple solutions, however the closest I've got is with an index function. I do however have to use one per row: =INDEX(B21:B190,MATCH($L$1,A21:A190,0)+1) the +2, then +3, then +4 etc...

Comment: *One formula can return multiple cells though can it not?* - yes it can, but it cannot **populate** multiple cells. There is a difference. This means you can have one formula find a bunch of cells and return these as an array. But a formula put in cell `A1` can never put a value into cell `A2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(QUERY({VLOOKUP(ROW(A3:A), 
 IF(A3:A<>"", {ROW(A3:A), A3:A}), 2, 1), B3:B}, 
 "select Col2 where Col1 = '"&D3&"'", 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks so much! I will mark as the answer as soon as I can :-)