# Filtering Google Sheet rows by groups (separated by empty rows). Filtering combined records

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, filtering

Have data in Google Sheet organized like this:
[image]

I receive the data in the format above. So records aggregated from differet sources.
One record in fact represented by single line of text in columns *B-H*. Data divided by records from **Manager 1** to **Manager 2** and so on.
But columns **I-L** have multiple lines and correspond to single records.

I colored them to see every single record:
[image]

***SourceSheet** (sample data) is available: [SourceSheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JqsV1upqVZ1FaVfdaQ9IoECGJytmdwwkvFZPT0AdOGg/edit?usp=drive_link)*

---

I need to filter that data by columns **B-H**. When I filter it as usual only one row filtered. How can I do filtering by grouped records separated by empty rows?

For example if I filter based on **Manager 1** I get result:
[image]

Is it possible to implement that by standard Google Sheet filter **or** Googe Apps Script?

Comment: To clarify, is the last screenshot your desired result? And would a script that fills e.g. the empty cells below "Manager 1" with "Manager 1" be an acceptable solution? Or is it required that those cells remain empty?

Comment: Actually it is needed for them to remain empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another suggestion you can try using `Google sheets formula`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(QUERY({VLOOKUP(ROW(Filtering2!D4:D), 
 IF(Filtering2!D4:D<>"", {ROW(Filtering2!D4:D), Filtering2!D4:D}), 2, 1), Filtering2!B4:L}, 
 "select * where Col1 = '"&B3&"'", 0)))
```

Where:

`D4:D` is the `Manager column`,

`B4:L` is the whole data,

`B3` is the drop-down I created, so that you can just select the Manager number you want to filter on.

**Filtering2 Sheet**
[image]

**RESULT:**
[image]

*Note: Just make sure to **format the dates** since the formula returns the date in numerical value*

Ref:
[Vlookup or Index and return multiple adjacent rows in next column in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59091498/vlookup-or-index-and-return-multiple-adjacent-rows-in-next-column-in-google-shee)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EapCfa5zc7WwNCjVkhaEsXxIxBczhk7lYfqp673-smw/edit?usp=drive_link. I put formula on A4 but it returns Value error. Why that happen?

Comment: I have tried your sheet, I observed that when you change your `Locale` and `TimeZone` in the `Settings`, it also affects the syntax of the formula. In your sheet, it is default at Russia and Katmandu; the Formula looks like this: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(QUERY({VLOOKUP(ROW(D5:D); IF(D5:D<>""; {ROW(D5:D)\ D5:D}); 2; 1)\ B5:L}; "select * where Col1 = '"&N4&"'"; 0)))`

Comment: Another thing to note is, you have to put it where it has enough space to populate what you are filtering on.

Comment: You can also use this formula to `remove` the repetitive `manager` word on `B4 and so on` as per my example result: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(QUERY({VLOOKUP(ROW(D5:D); 
 IF(D5:D<>""; {ROW(D5:D)\ D5:D}); 2; 1)\ B5:L}; 
 "select Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12 where Col1 = '"&N4&"'"; 0)))` . NOTE: That I have Adjusted the formula based on your `Locale and Timezone`

Answer (score 2):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

*Create a `drop-down validation` in **Cell_D1**(to pick from the range **D4:D**)*

[image]

*Add this `custom formula` to header Manager in **Cell_D3***

```js
=$D$1=chooserows(tocol($D$3:D4;1);-1)
```

***IMP***: *You need to **click on OK button** everytime you change the drop-down to pick a manager*

[image]